# Get audio variants (dolby, lossless, AAC) of songs in apple music library using apple script

Tags: applescript, music, apple-music, streaming

Apple Music API can return all [audioVariants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/songs/attributes) of a song. I'm trying to get this info using apple script but unable to figure out.
I need the highlighted information (`Dolby Atmos, Lossless Audio, AAC Audio`) using apple script.

[image: Available formats]

`properties` doesn't have this information.

```
tell application "Music"
    set sel to a reference to every track of playlist "All"
    repeat with this_track in sel
        get this_track's properties
    end repeat
end tell
```

Result :

```
{class:shared track, id:12188, index:2, name:"Worth It (feat. Kid Ink)", persistent ID:"472E227FDCE8ED13", database ID:3681, date added:date "Wednesday, 9 August 2017 at 1:04:09 PM", time:"3:44", duration:224.572998046875, artist:"Fifth Harmony", album artist:"Fifth Harmony", composer:"TBD", album:"Reflection (Deluxe)", genre:"Pop", bit rate:256, sample rate:44100, track count:14, track number:4, disc count:1, disc number:1, size:7997983, volume adjustment:0, year:2015, comment:"Sexy", EQ:"", kind:"Apple Music AAC audio file", media kind:song, modification date:date "Wednesday, 9 August 2017 at 1:04:09 PM", enabled:true, start:0.0, finish:224.572998046875, played count:20, played date:date "Friday, 19 August 2022 at 9:07:41 AM", skipped count:4, skipped date:date "Saturday, 18 April 2020 at 8:45:24 PM", compilation:false, rating:0, bpm:0, grouping:"", bookmarkable:false, bookmark:0.0, shufflable:true, lyrics:"", category:"", description:"", episode number:0, unplayed:false, sort name:"Worth It (feat. Kid Ink)", sort album:"Reflection (Deluxe)", sort artist:"Fifth Harmony", sort composer:"", sort album artist:"", release date:date "Friday, 30 January 2015 at 1:30:00 PM", loved:true, disliked:false, album loved:false, album disliked:false, cloud status:subscription, work:"", movement:"", movement number:0, movement count:0}
```